# write CSV columns out in a different order in Python

Tags: python, csv

I realize this is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885324/is-it-possible-to-keep-the-column-order-using-the-python-csv-dictreader).  However, I have a CSV file that always comes in the same format that I need to write out with columns in a different order to move it down the data processing pipeline.  If my csv file contains headers and data like this:

```
Date,Individual,Plate,Sample,test,QC
03312011,Indiv098,P342,A1,deep,passed
03312011,Indiv113,P352,C3,deep,passed
```

How would I write out a csv file with the same columns as the original input csv but in the following order:

```
test,QC,Plate,Sample
deep,passed,P342,A1
deep,passed,P352,C3
```

My initial thought was to do something like this:

```
f = open('test.csv')
lines = f.readlines()
for l in lines:
    h = l.split(",")
    a, b, c, d, e, f  = h
    for line in h:
        print e, f, c, d,
```

Comment: If you just need a tool rather than code to do this, take a look at my FOSS tool at http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ which makes re-ordering of CSV fields (among other things) trivial.

Comment: Famous Last Words: "file that always comes in the same format"

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: Famous Last Thoughts: "My CSV file can be parsed successfully with `str.split(',')`"

Comment: new_row = [row[4], row[5], row[2], row[3]]
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905165/replace-data-in-csv-file-using-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's the slightest chance that the input file or the output file won't have the same layout each time, here's a more general way to get your "reorderfunc":

```
writenames = "test,QC,Plate,Sample".split(",") # example
reader = csv.reader(input_file_handle)
writer = csv.writer(output_file_handle)
# don't forget to open both files in binary mode (2.x)
# or with `newline=''` (3.x)
readnames = reader.next()
name2index = dict((name, index) for index, name in enumerate(readnames))
writeindices = [name2index[name] for name in writenames]
reorderfunc = operator.itemgetter(*writeindices)
writer.writerow(writenames)
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(reorderfunc(row))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
reorderfunc = operator.itemgetter(4, 5, 2, 3)

 ...

newrow = reorderfunc(oldrow)
 ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Given your input as `src.csv`:

```
import csv

with open('x.csv','rb') as i:
    with open('y.csv','wb') as o:
        r = csv.DictReader(i)
        w = csv.DictWriter(o,'test QC Plate Sample'.split(),extrasaction='ignore')
        w.writeheader()
        for a in r:
            w.writerow(a)
```

#### Output

```
test,QC,Plate,Sample
deep,passed,P342,A1
deep,passed,P352,C3
```

Comment: the best python working python code, who cares for speed nowadays thanks to moore laws

Answer (score 0):

```
#Use CSV library
import csv
media = {}
files=['Online.txt']
directory = "C:/directory/"
rowCnt=0

for file in files:

    file=directory+file

    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|') #use pipe delimiter

        for row in reader:
            rowCnt+=1
            if (rowCnt % 1000) == 0:
                print ('"%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s"')% (row[1],row[4],row[14],row[17],row[18],row[24],row[25],row[28],row[30])
```