# python: copy selected csv columns to other csv file when one header is empty

Tags: python, parsing, csv, string

I have some large csv file, with about 200 header names (the first one of which is empty).
I want to get some chosen columns and copy them to a new output.csv file.  My problem comes grabbing the header which has no name! (empty first element in the header)

So the input.csv looks something like,

```
            ,header1,header2,header3,header4, ... , header200
            value0, value2, value2, value3, value4, ..., value200
            ,2,3,30,,, ... , 10
            66,2,3,30,, ... , 10
```

etc (all rows have the same number of elements even if empty).

After reading various questions I've recycled some code from
[write CSV columns out in a different order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117868/write-csv-columns-out-in-a-different-order-in-python)

to write,

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter         

SelectedSignals = ['header1',  'header4'] 



fiin=open('input.csv','rb') #open to read "r" in binary mode "b"
fiout=open('output.csv','wb') #open to write "w" in binary mode "b"

reader = csv.reader(fiin, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(fiout, delimiter=',')

AllSignalNames = reader.next()
name2index = dict((name, index) for index, name in enumerate(AllSignalNames))
writeindices = [name2index[name] for name in SelectedSignals]
reorderfunc = itemgetter(*writeindices) # itemgetter was imported from operator module
writer.writerow(SelectedSignals)

for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(reorderfunc(row))
```

this gives the desired output,
say,

```
            ,header1,header4
            value0, value4
            ,30
            66,30
```

but the problem is doing,

```
  SelectedSignals = [' ', 'header1',  'header4']
```

to grab the first column. which returns **KeyError**

I'm a python beginner, so any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSV format, the first header should be a zero-length string (`''`), not a space (`' '`), which is what you use in `SelectedSignals`.

You could also add a fake column name to your `name2index` dict, for example `name2index['header0'] = 0` just after `name2index = ...` and then use `'header0'` in `SelectedSignals`.

Alternatively, you could use a default value for the dict (when it can't find the header you want, it would use this default value): `name2index.get(name, 0)` instead of `name2index[name]` in your `writeindices` expression.