# Nested with blocks in Python, level of nesting variable

Tags: python, csv

I would like to combine columns of various csv files into one csv file, with a new heading, concatenated horizontally. I want to only select certain columns,chosen by heading. There are different columns in each of the files to be combined.

Example input:

freestream.csv:

```
static pressure,static temperature,relative Mach number
1.01e5,288,5.00e-02
```

fan.csv:

```
static pressure,static temperature,mass flow
0.9e5,301,72.9
```

exhaust.csv:

```
static pressure,static temperature,mass flow
1.7e5,432,73.1
```

Desired output:

combined.csv:

```
P_amb,M0,Ps_fan,W_fan,W_exh
1.01e5,5.00e-02,0.9e6,72.9,73.1
```

Possible call to the function:

```
reorder_multiple_CSVs(["freestream.csv","fan.csv","exhaust.csv"],
    "combined.csv",["static pressure,relative Mach number",
    "static pressure,mass flow","mass flow"],
    "P_amb,M0,Ps_fan,W_fan,W_exh")
```

Here is a previous version of the code, with only one input file allowed. I wrote this with help from [write CSV columns out in a different order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117868/write-csv-columns-out-in-a-different-order-in-python):

```
def reorder_CSV(infilename,outfilename,oldheadings,newheadings):
    with open(infilename) as infile:
       with open(outfilename,'w') as outfile:
           reader = csv.reader(infile)
           writer = csv.writer(outfile)
           readnames = reader.next()
           name2index = dict((name,index) for index, name in enumerate(readnames))
           writeindices = [name2index[name] for name in oldheadings.split(",")]
           reorderfunc = operator.itemgetter(*writeindices)
           writer.writerow(newheadings.split(","))
           for row in reader:
               towrite = reorderfunc(row)
               if isinstance(towrite,str):
                   writer.writerow([towrite])
               else:
                   writer.writerow(towrite)
```

So what I have figure out, in order to adapt this to multiple files, is:

-I need infilename, oldheadings, and newheadings to be a list now (all of the same length)

-I need to iterate over the list of input files to make a list of readers

-readnames can also be a list, iterating over the readers

-which means I can make name2index a list of dictionaries

One thing I don't know how to do, is use the keyword `with`, nested n-levels deep, when n is known only at run time. I read this: [How can I open multiple files using "with open" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/python-open-multiple-files-using-with-open) but that seems to only work when you know how many files you need to open.

Or is there a better way to do this?

I am quite new to python so I appreciate any tips you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only replying to the part about opening multiple files with `with`, where the number of files is unknown before. It shouldn't be too hard to write your own [contextmanager](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), something like this (completely untested):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def open_many_files(filenames):
    files = [open(filename) for filename in filenames]
    try:
        yield files
    finally:
        for f in files:
            f.close()
```

Which you would use like this:

```
innames = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']
outname = 'out.csv'
with open_many(innames) as infiles, open(outname, 'w') as outfile:
    for infile in infiles:
        do_stuff(in_file)
```

There is also a function that [does something similar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested), but it is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it tomorrow and try to implement the rest.

Comment: It took me a while (got sidetracked by other projects) but I fixed & implemented your solution and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but I wanted to expand on Bas Swinckels answer. He had a couple small inconsistencies in his very helpful answer and I wanted to give the correect code.

Here is what I did, and it worked.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import csv
import operator
import itertools as IT

@contextmanager
def open_many_files(filenames):
    files=[open(filename,'r') for filename in filenames]
    try:
        yield files
    finally:
        for f in files:
            f.close()

def reorder_multiple_CSV(infilenames,outfilename,oldheadings,newheadings):
    with open_many_files(filter(None,infilenames.split(','))) as handles:
        with open(outfilename,'w') as outfile:
            readers=[csv.reader(f) for f in handles]
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            reorderfunc=[]
            for i, reader in enumerate(readers):
                readnames = reader.next()
                name2index = dict((name,index) for index, name in enumerate(readnames))
                writeindices = [name2index[name] for name in filter(None,oldheadings[i].split(","))]
                reorderfunc.append(operator.itemgetter(*writeindices))
            writer.writerow(filter(None,newheadings.split(",")))
            for rows in IT.izip_longest(*readers,fillvalue=['']*2):
                towrite=[]
                for i, row in enumerate(rows):
                   towrite.extend(reorderfunc[i](row))
                if isinstance(towrite,str):
                   writer.writerow([towrite])
                else:
                   writer.writerow(towrite)
```