# Original order of columns in csv not retained in unicodecsv.DictReader

Tags: python-3.x, csv, python-unicode, ordereddictionary

I am trying read a CSV file into python 3 using `unicodecsv` library. Code follows :

```
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f: 
    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
    Student_Data = list(reader)
```

But the order of the columns in the CSV file is not retained when I output any element from the `Student_Data`. The output contains any random order of the columns. Is there anything wrong with the code? How do I fix this?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885324/is-it-possible-to-keep-the-column-order-using-the-python-csv-dictreader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [csv.DictReader documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), the DictReader object behaves like a `dict` - so it is not ordered.

You can obtain the list of the fieldnames with:

```
reader.fieldnames
```

But if you only want to obtain a list of the field values, in original order, you can just use a normal reader:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f: 
    reader = unicodecsv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        Student_Data = row
```