# Create list of dictionaries from CSV in the same order using Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

Consider a CSV,

```
col1, col2, col3
1000, Star, True
2000, Moon, False
```

How to create a list of dictionaries in the same order like this

```
[{'col1': '1000', 'col2': 'Star', 'col3': 'TRUE'}, {'col1': '2000', 'col2': 'Moon', 'col3': 'FALSE'}]
```

I have tried with following code but not getting in the same order

```
with open('sample.csv') as f:
    rows = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()}
        for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
```

Output of above code,

```
[{'col2': 'Star', 'col3': 'TRUE', 'col1': '1000'}, {'col2': 'Moon', 'col3': 'FALSE', 'col1': '2000'}]
```

Is there any solution to get in the same order?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885324/is-it-possible-to-keep-the-column-order-using-the-python-csv-dictreader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dictionaries are inherently unordered, you need wrap an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) on each of the dictionaries in your list, which need to be sorted beforehand:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('sample.csv') as f:
    rows = [OrderedDict(sorted(dict((k, v) for k, v in row.items()).items())) for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]

>>> print(rows)
[OrderedDict([('col1', '1000'), ('col2', 'Star'), ('col3', 'True')]), OrderedDict([('col1', '2000'), ('col2', 'Moon'), ('col3', 'False')])]
```

And works normally:

```
>>> print(rows[0]['col1'])
1000
>>> print(rows[1]['col1'])
2000
print([key for key in rows[0]])
['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

**Note:** You can't replace the `OrderedDict()` wrapping in the output with a normal dictionary, otherwise it will be unordered again. This is one of the prices we have to pay if we want ordered dictionaries in python.

Comment: I just started with Python. Seems okay for the time being. But I will surely look deep on this

Comment: @3P3 This is really the only easy way to do this. Do you really have to have `col1`, `col2` and `col3` ordered?

Comment: Yes, since the data need to pass and create a XPT file. thats expecting the order same. Also this matter for QA as well